# Can i use React360 to create a 360 view tour, on a project that i'm trying to develop using Angular front-end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, react-360

so I'm trying to create a project/website using angular for the front-end and node.js for the back-end. i need to create 360° panorama for multiple images just like what you see on google street map, where you are able to look at some places of the street in the panorama mode.
So to do that, i accidentally found the library react-360 that will help me to create those scenes; but since i'm using Angular, do you think it gonna be helpful or not? i'm a newbie here so if you have any other suggestions, i would love to know

Answer (score 0):

angular
nodejs
contact me ill provide you with the solution